# Como usar um variável global em uma função em python?

Tags: python, variáveis-globais

Eu estou tentando fazer um sistema de lootbox em python, mas não consigo usar um variável de fora dentro da função

```
from main import player
from random import randint
p1 = player
class item:
    def lootbox(a,c):
        v = 0
        b = 0
        if c == 'C':
            if LbCn < a:
                print("Você não tem esse tanto de lootbox comum")
            if LbCn >= a:
                while v != a:
                    num = randint(1,10)
                    inv.append(LbC[num])
                    LbCn -= 1
                    print('Você ganhou...')
                    p1.tempo(1,3)
                    print(LbC[num])
                    LbCn -=1
                    v += 1
    inv = []

    #Quantas lootboxes o player tem de cada tipo
    LbCn = 5
    LbRn =0
    LbEn = 0
    LbLn = 0

    #O que se pode ganhar na lootbox comum
    LbC = ['Vara de Madeira Podre', 'Isca feita de pão','Anzol Enferrujado','Vara de Madeira','Chapéu de Couro Feio', 'Isca','10 reais','Sanduiche Mofado','Nada!!!','Balde Meio Amassado']
lootbox(1,'C')
```

Answer (score 3):

Você não precisa usar variáveis globais (o que não é boa prática) e sim definir corretamente a classe que construiu:

```py
from main import player
from random import randint

p1 = player


class Item:
    #
    # --> crie uma função __init__() e inicialize as variáveis que precisa
    #
    def __init__(self):

        self.inv = []

        # Quantas lootboxes o player tem de cada tipo
        self.LbCn = 5
        ...

        # O que se pode ganhar na lootbox comum
        self.LbC = [
            "Vara de Madeira Podre",
            ...
        ]

    # --> não esqueça de acrescentar o "self" no começo do método.
    def lootbox(self, a, c):
        v = 0
        b = 0
        if c == "C":
            # --> coloque "self." na frente das variáveis definidas no __init__()
            # --> e indica o escopo da classe e não da variável dentro do método.
            if self.LbCn < a:
                print("Você não tem esse tanto de lootbox comum")
            if self.LbCn >= a:
                while v != a:
                ...

# instancie a classe e chame o método desejado.
i = Item()
i.lootbox(1, "C")
```

E, para maiores detalhes, consulte a [documentação da linguagem](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).